# Azure Files: System error 64 has occurred

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have Azure Files Preview enabled to my Azure account. I have created a new storage account, created a share following the [instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/11/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx).

Now when I try to map the share to a network drive (just as the aforementioned article says), I get the following error:

```
net use z: \\mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\share /u:mystorageaccount mystorageaccountkey
```

> System error 64 has occurred.
>
> The specified network name is no longer available.

What causes this?

Comment: Are you trying to perform this operation on your computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operation you're trying to perform is not possible and that's why you're getting this error. I made the same mistake :).

You can only mount a share from a Virtual Machine running in the same region as your storage account. This was also mentioned in the blog post by storage team though I must say it was not very clear.

Comment: You might be referring to the blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/11/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) which specifies `Once your share is created, it can be accessed via the SMB or REST protocol from any Azure node (VM/Worker/Web role) hosted in the same region as the storage account hosting the share.` under Step 4 of 'Getting Started'.

Answer (score 0):

To update the current answer, one can now map from OnPremise **if the OS supports SMB 3.0**. As per [Get started with Azure File storage on Windows - Mount the file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share) it states (emphasis mine):

> With support for SMB 3.0, File storage now supports encryption and
>   persistent handles from SMB 3.0 clients. Support for encryption means
>   that SMB 3.0 clients can mount a file share from anywhere, including
>   from:
>
> - An Azure virtual machine in the same region (also supported by SMB
>     2.1)
> - An Azure virtual machine in a different region (SMB 3.0 only)
> - **An on-premises client application** (SMB 3.0 only)

and lists the OS's and their SMB versions.